# Creating WCF Service at runtime

Tags: wcf, wsdl, reflection.emit

We are going to build a web service from metadata read at runtime.  I mean the entire web service:  the signatures, contracts and implementation.

There are two main paths I see from here.

The first path is that you generate code.  Either you generate C# code in strings and compile it on the fly or more elegantly (and complicatedly), you emit MSIL code.  This way you have WCF code and WCF will take care of generating the WSDL from it.

The second path is to use a generic service.  A service with an operation Message Process(Message) accepting everything.  We still want to expose the service as a 'normal' service, so I would need a WSDL somewhere.  How can I create a WSDL?  I thought about using System.ServiceModel.Description until I realised that deep inside, this API depends on concrete types.  With this approach we wouldn't have any data contract type and would process XML on the fly, using metadata to interpret it.  So we need somehow to generate the WSDL.  Is that a crazy idea?  WSDL has quite a complicated spec...

A third option would be to use an hybrid approach, emitting types just to create signatures but implementing the service using non-emitted code (reflecting on emitted types).  Weird, but might be simpler than hand crafting WSDL by hand...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

It's a pain to do, but possible to emitting types. Create your .svc and point it at your custom ServiceHostFactory:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Factory="Foo.FooServiceHostFactory" %>

[ServiceContract]
public class FooService { }
```

Your ServiceHostFactory is where you generate your operation contracts, types that go with it, etc:

```
public class FooServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory {
public override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) {
    ServiceHost serviceHost = new FooServiceHost(baseAddresses);
    serviceHost.AddDefaultEndpoints();
    GenerateServiceOperations(serviceHost);
    return serviceHost;
}

private void GenerateServiceOperations(ServiceHost serviceHost) {
    var methodNames = new[] {
        new { Name = "Add" },
        new { Name = "Subtract" },
        new { Name = "Multiply" }
    };

    foreach (var method in methodNames) {
        foreach (var endpoint in serviceHost.Description.Endpoints) {
            var contract = endpoint.Contract;
            var operationDescription = new OperationDescription("Operation" + method.Name, contract);
            var requestMessageDescription = new MessageDescription(string.Format("{0}{1}/Operation{2}", contract.Namespace, contract.Name, method.Name), MessageDirection.Input);
            var responseMessageDescription = new MessageDescription(string.Format("{0}{1}/Operation{2}Response", contract.Namespace, contract.Name, method.Name), MessageDirection.Output);

            var elements = new List<FooDataItem>();
            elements.Add(new FooDataItem { Name = "X", DataType = typeof(int) });
            elements.Add(new FooDataItem { Name = "Y", DataType = typeof(int) });

            //note: for a complex type it gets more complicated, but the same idea using reflection during invoke()
            //object type = TypeFactory.CreateType(method.Name, elements);
            //var arrayOfType = Array.CreateInstance(type.GetType(), 0);

            //var parameter = new MessagePartDescription(method.Name + "Operation", contract.Namespace);
            //parameter.Type = arrayOfType.GetType();
            //parameter.Index = 0;
            //requestMessageDescription.Body.Parts.Add(parameter);

            var retVal = new MessagePartDescription("Result", contract.Namespace);
            retVal.Type = typeof(int);
            responseMessageDescription.Body.ReturnValue = retVal;

            int indexer = 0;
            foreach (var element in elements) {
                var parameter = new MessagePartDescription(element.Name, contract.Namespace);
                parameter.Type = element.DataType;
                parameter.Index = indexer++;
                requestMessageDescription.Body.Parts.Add(parameter);
            }

            operationDescription.Messages.Add(requestMessageDescription);
            operationDescription.Messages.Add(responseMessageDescription);
            operationDescription.Behaviors.Add(new DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operationDescription));
            operationDescription.Behaviors.Add(new FooOperationImplementation());
            contract.Operations.Add(operationDescription);
        }
    }
}

protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) {
    return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
}
```

}
In the ServiceHostFactory you define the behaviors along with the metadata, so your behavior would need to implement IOperationBehavior and IOperationInvoker (or you could implement them separately) and look something like this:

```
public class FooOperationImplementation : IOperationBehavior, IOperationInvoker {
OperationDescription operationDescription;
DispatchOperation dispatchOperation;

public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {

}

public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation) {

}

public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation) {
    this.operationDescription = operationDescription;
    this.dispatchOperation = dispatchOperation;

    dispatchOperation.Invoker = this;
}

public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription) {

}

public object[] AllocateInputs() {
    return new object[2];
}

public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs) {
    //this would ALL be dynamic as well depending on how you are creating your service
    //for example, you could keep metadata in the database and then look it up, etc
    outputs = new object[0];

    switch (operationDescription.Name) {
        case "OperationAdd":
            return (int)inputs[0] + (int)inputs[1];
        case "OperationSubtract":
            return (int)inputs[0] - (int)inputs[1];
        case "OperationMultiply":
            return (int)inputs[0] * (int)inputs[1];
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("wtf");
    }
}

public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state) {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Method is not asynchronous.");
}

public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result) {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Method is not asynchronous.");
}

public bool IsSynchronous {
    get { return true; }
}
```

}

For complex types, this is where you need to make a judgement call, which is the root of your question, is how to emit the types. Here's an example, but you can do it any way you can see fit. I'm calling this in my ServiceHostFactory (warning: it's demo code)

```
static public class TypeFactory {
    static object _lock = new object();
    static AssemblyName assemblyName;
    static AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder;
    static ModuleBuilder module;

    static TypeFactory() {
        lock (_lock) {
            assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
            assemblyName.Name = "FooBarAssembly";
            assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("FooBarModule");
        }
    }

    static public object CreateType(string typeName, List<FooDataItem> elements) {
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = module.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);

        foreach(var element in elements) {
            string propertyName = element.Name;
            Type dataType = element.DataType;

            FieldBuilder field = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, dataType, FieldAttributes.Private);
            PropertyBuilder property =
                typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName,
                                    PropertyAttributes.None,
                                    dataType,
                                    new Type[] { dataType });

            MethodAttributes GetSetAttr =
                    MethodAttributes.Public |
                    MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

            MethodBuilder currGetPropMthdBldr =
                typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_value",
                                            GetSetAttr,
                                            dataType,
                                            Type.EmptyTypes);

            ILGenerator currGetIL = currGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder currSetPropMthdBldr =
                typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_value",
                                            GetSetAttr,
                                            null,
                                            new Type[] { dataType });

            ILGenerator currSetIL = currSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            property.SetGetMethod(currGetPropMthdBldr);
            property.SetSetMethod(currSetPropMthdBldr);
        }

        Type generetedType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        return Activator.CreateInstance(generetedType);
    }
}
```

update: I wrote a quick example and it is available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1n1KXWaAMLa-LFAgxMon4V4mQQs7k8C7T).

Comment: The link no longer exists

Comment: I found the old zip file, added it to google drive and updated the link. HTH